# How to copy directories and their time stamp from source to destination?

Tags: python

By using the code below, I am getting the directory from the source to the destination. However, the time of the destination directory and the source is changed.

```
import os,time,os.path,shutil
shutil.copytree(sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath)
```

I would like to copy the source directory with their time stamp. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) This should work. ["Permissions and times of directories are copied with copystat()"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) 2) What do you mean by "the source is changed"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping file attributes on a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685217/keeping-file-attributes-on-a-copy)

Answer (score 0):

First **warning** on the **docs**:

> Even the higher-level file copying functions (shutil.copy(),
>   shutil.copy2()) **cannot copy all file metadata**.
>
> On POSIX platforms, this means that file owner and group are lost as
>   well as ACLs. On Mac OS, the resource fork and other metadata are not
>   used. This means that resources will be lost and file type and creator
>   codes will not be correct. On Windows, file owners, ACLs and alternate
>   data streams are not copied.

`shutil.copytree` uses `shutil.copy2()`by default:

> Permissions and times of directories are copied with copystat(),
>   individual files are copied using shutil.copy2()

Comment: shutil.copytree copy all, but with new time stamp of directory. But I  want source directory time stamp in destination.