# How to use Curl to copy file within same server , across different directories, dont know the hostname?

Tags: python, linux, curl

I am using curl -F option to import a file to remote server. Everything worked well.

```
curl -k -u admin:admin -F:operation=import -F:contentType=json -F:name=test \
  -F:replace=true -F:replaceProperties=true -F:contentFile=@./model.json \
  http://localhost:8802/conf/models
```

However, I want to copy this file model.json to another directory, using the above -F options . I don't know the hostname. Is there a way in Curl to do?

I tried to copy the file using python, which worked well, but I need to use Curl using the -F options to retain the properties of the file.

Comment: re-excute the same cmd but change the target directory? I'll be surprised if you can get a copy to work from one remote dir to differnt remote dir on the same machine, but I'm not a curl expert And it's possible I have misinterpreted your question. Good luck!

Comment: When you tried Python, did you [**use copy2()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685217/keeping-file-attributes-on-a-copy)?